# rails .find returns a special unkown error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my form I have this selection field.

```
<%= f.collection_select :channel_id, @channels, :id, :channelname, {prompt: (t "channel.add.prompt")}, class: "form-control" %>
```

Looks perfekt and displays a selection with all the availabe channels.

Now I want to find it with the .find function after sending form. Code looks like this:

```
@channel = Channel.find(params[:channel_id])
@vid.channel = @channel
```

In params the channel_id is display with id correctly ... but I got this error:

[image]

Whats the problem in this case? Don't understand it ...

Thanks for your help.

EDIT - params

[image]

Comment: Can you post the `params` that you received for that action?

Comment: of course, added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Couldn't find Channel with 'id'=

When you look at the `params`, you got `channel_id` inside `vid` hash. So you can't access it with `params[:channel_id]`. You should do the below

```
@channel = Channel.find(params[:vid][:channel_id])
```